# How to remove <br> at the beginning and at the end of a string in javascript using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this resulted string:

```
 <br><br><br>This is an example!<br>Test1!<br>Test2!<br><br>
```

**Attempted code:**

```
 var string = "<br><br><br>This is an example!<br>Test1<br>Test2<br><br>";

 var remove = string.replace(/^(<br>)+/g, "");
 console.log(remove);
```

But these codes is removing only the first br's in a string when I add `$` at the end of `(<br>)`, so my code will fail. My question is how to remove the `<br>` at the beginning and at the end of a string?

**Expected output:** when used console.log

```
   This is an example!<br>Test1!<br>Test2!
```

Comment: Throw an error? I can hardly believe. Which one? Where exactly did you add the `$`?

Comment: What I mean is it will do nothing. And I will throw an error.

Comment: Should just be like reg exp to trim whitespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, what you're looking for is an *alternation*: `|`

```
var remove = string.replace(/^(<br>)+|(<br>)+$/g, "");
```

That will match `^(<br>)+` *or* `(<br>)+$`, and since your regex is global, both occurences will be replaced.

**Live Example:**

```js
var string = "<br><br><br>This is an example!<br>Test1<br>Test2<br><br>";

var remove = string.replace(/^(<br>)+|(<br>)+$/g, "");
snippet.log(remove);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

I would also replace the capture groups with non-capturing groups (`(?:...)`), but that's probably just me being OTT:

```
var remove = string.replace(/^(?:<br>)+|(?:<br>)+$/g, "");
```